# Which DIMM slots to install my RAM into?

Tags: memory

I am installing some DDR4 RAM into a computer and I am slightly confused by this chart in the motherboard's manual:

[image: Motherboard Manual Page]

There are four physical DIMM slots and the following is my understanding of the terminology I just learned:  A1 and A2 are on a channel while B1 and B2 comprise another channel.  If I install both sticks of RAM into a single channel (A1,A2 or B1,B2) then I'm taking advantage of my motherboard's [dual channel](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1664/~/what-is-dual-channel-memory%3F) technology, which should increase overall memory bandwidth.

Except the RAM that I have is [dual rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_rank) with a frequency of 2400Mhz which seems to mean I am stuck installing into slots A2 and B2 with no possibility of adding more RAM of this rank/frequency.

First, and most importantly - am I reading this correctly?  And second, in terms of upgrades would it be better to move to four sticks of single rank RAM at a higher frequency (2400) or four sticks of double rank RAM at 2133?  I really have no idea how to balance between SR/DR versus frequency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Except the RAM that I have is dual rank with a frequency of 2400Mhz which seems to mean I am stuck installing into slots A2 and B2 with no possibility of adding more RAM of this rank/frequency.

Your motherboard clearly supports 4 dual rank DDR4 modules.  It just won’t support 2400 MHz frequency modules if you fill both channels.

> [image]
>
> And second, in terms of upgrades would it be better to move to four sticks of single rank RAM at a higher frequency (2400) or four sticks of double rank RAM at 2133?

You will be hard pressed to actually see any difference outside of a memory benchmark which are not always realistic.  Your 2400 MHz modules will simply downclock to the next lowest frequency.

> First, and most importantly - am I reading this correctly?

Your motherboard doesn’t support running 4 2400 MHz+ modules.  Your motherboard supports slightly slower modules, which will make very little impact, on your overal performance.

I only recommend huge frequency jumps, a 377 MHz difference, won’t be measurable outside of memory benchmarks.